# Laravel Livewire refreshing parent full-page component

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using a full-page component that contains a modal child component that handles updating the model. When the user clicks save on the modal and the update is made, I want to refresh the parent component, which is really the overall page. However, when I save, nothing happens.

Here's my parent Component code:

```
class LocationComponent extends Component
{
    public Location $location;
    public $client;
    public $legalEntities;
    public $smsTypes;
    public $clientContacts;
    public $locationContacts;

    protected $listeners = [
        'refreshParent' => '$refresh'
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->legalEntities = LegalEntityType::all();
        $this->smsTypes = SmsType::all();
        $this->roles = Role::all();
        $this->client = $this->location->client()->first();
        $this->clientContacts = $this->client->users()->get();
        $this->locationContacts = $this->location->users()->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.locations.edit');
    }
}
```

And here's the child component (modal):

```
class LocationEditModal extends Component
{

    public $states;
    public Location $location;

    protected $rules = [
       ...
    ];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->states = USState::all();
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.location-edit-modal');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        $this->location->save($validatedData);
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModal');
        $this->emit('refreshParent');

    }
}
```

I added this code in my parent blade file to see if the event was firing, and it appears it's not:

```
 <script>
      Livewire.on('refreshParent', event => {
          alert('the refreshParent event was fired');
      });
 </script>
```

Here's the route from my web routes file:

```
  Route::get('/locations/{location}', [LocationComponent::class, '__invoke'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('locations.edit');
```

I've also tried changing `$refresh` to just `render`, but that also didn't work.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, after moving my event listener script to my main layout file, I'm getting the event fired alert now. Still no update of the parent component, but it's a start.

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm wondering if it's how I'm referencing the model data in my parent component blade view. I'm just referencing it how I normally would like this:

`<p class="d-flex" id="name">{{ $location->name }}</p>`

I'm not sure if my parent component is maybe not getting the updated `$location`?

**UPDATE 3:**

Based on my last update, I thought maybe I need to refresh the model, so I tried adding this to my parent component mount method, but it didn't work either:

`$this->location->refresh();`

Not sure if this is relevant, but in my parent component, which has the `$location`, it's calling the child modal component like this:

`<livewire:location-edit-modal :location="$location"/>`

Again, just putting that in there in case it helps with a solution. I don't know if I'm doing some kind of a circular thing that's not going to work right? Grasping at straws at this point..

**RESOLUTION**

Ok, this probably won't help anyone else, but it seems the theme I am using had some left over Laravel 7 things that weren't removed (I think).  Per the Livewire docs about upgrading (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading) you're supposed to remove the `->namespace($this->namespace)` line from the RouteServiceProvider if you're on version 7 of Laravel. Version 8 already has it removed. I thought I was using Laravel 8, but maybe there was an upgrade done on this theme and it was never removed.

The other problem was I was using `@yield('content')` in my layout, and that's apparently not supported anymore. With version 2 of livewire, it should use the `{{ $slot }}` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sharing your actual code here? I'm a bit confused since neither your `LocationComponent` or `LocationEditModal` components ever actually sets a value to `$this->location`.

Either way, there is no need to re-render the whole `LocationComponent` modal, you can just refresh the `$this->location` to the updated version of the location to update the values.

Something like this should work:

```php
class LocationComponent extends Component {

  protected $listeners = [
    'locationUpdated'
  ];  

  public function locationUpdated()
  {
    $this->location->refresh();
  }
}
```

```php
class LocationEditModal extends Component {
  public function save()
  {
    $this->emit('locationUpdated');  
  }
}
```

I don't believe you shared you're actual code, so it's hard to make an accurate recommendation, but it doesn't seem like your modal needs be a separate component at all. Your `LocationComponent` is already isolated to a single Location anyways; I would just have the save/update logic on the `LocationComponent` directly instead of a whole separate component.

Comment: This is good feedback, thank you. I'm trying this out now, and yeah, maybe the separate location modal component was a design flaw. I started with the modal to tinker around with livewire, and then never went back and thought through what I was actually doing.

Comment: As far as my code, my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) was that route model binding would allow Livewire to know what you were passing to the mount method and you could just leave it out. I've tried both ways and they both seem to function just fine.